# Storm-Kafka-client from Storm 1.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

Based on the Storm documentation supported implementation of  `KafkaSpout` is based on the old consumer API. I noticed the external package has another implementation named `storm-kafka-client`.

https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka-client

It is unclear if the new client release in `1.0.1` is production ready. Does anyone have experience running it?

Answer (score 2):

I posted the same question to the Storm mail list. 
the new API is production ready. We should use 1.x branch.
I plan to test with

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm/storm-kafka-client -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Will update on the progress.

Comment: hi @YaRiK, 
I am looking for a quick example on how to use storm-kafka-client module!

Can you please share any example code, if you have already written one ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below Code works for me fine!!!

```
public TopologyBuilder myTopology() {

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    try {       
        KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> kafkaSpoutConfig = getKafkaSpoutConfig("KAFKA_IP:9092", KAFKA_TOPIC);          
        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout<>(kafkaSpoutConfig);
        builder.setSpout("kafkaSpout", kafkaSpout, 2 * 2);
        builder.setBolt("Bolt-1", new TestBolt(), parallelism).shuffleGrouping("kafkaSpout", KAFKA_TOPIC);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    return builder;
}
```

Configure Spout.

```
protected KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> getKafkaSpoutConfig(String bootstrapServers ,String topic) {
    ByTopicRecordTranslator<String, String> trans = new ByTopicRecordTranslator<>(
        (r) -> new Values(r.topic(), r.partition(), r.offset(), r.key(), r.value()),
        new Fields("topic", "partition", "offset", "key", "value"), topic);

    Builder<String, String> builder = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, new String[]{topic});

    return builder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, topic)
        .setProcessingGuarantee(ProcessingGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .setRetry(getRetryService())
        .setRecordTranslator(trans)
        .setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(10_000)
        .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(UNCOMMITTED_EARLIEST)
        .setMaxUncommittedOffsets(1000)
        .build();
}
```

For configure failed messages retyr logic

```
protected KafkaSpoutRetryService getRetryService() {
    return new KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff(TimeInterval.microSeconds(500),
        TimeInterval.milliSeconds(2), Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeInterval.seconds(10));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following maven dependency for storm 1.1.0

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
         <version>0.9.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

You may face some more dependency issue which you can resolve by adding the required jars.

Also the dependency in java code will change from org.backtype.storm.XXXXX to org.apache.storm.XXXXX